# Stringbuilder.ToString() Converting " and ' symbol generate &#39; and &quot; in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, stringbuilder

I wrote some dynamic javascript code into StringBuilder, but when I am converting StringBuilder object to string it converting symbols into html code. below is my code:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder gastring = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
  @foreach (var line in OrderLines)
 {
     gastring.AppendLine("ga('ecommerce:addItem', {");
                gastring.AppendLine("id:\"" + line.OrderNumber + "\",       // Order ID");
                gastring.AppendLine("sku:\"" + line.SkuCode + "\",                                     // SKU");
                gastring.AppendLine("name:" + Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(line.SkuName) + ",                                  // Product Name ");
                gastring.AppendLine("category:\"" + " " + "\",                                    // Category");
                gastring.AppendLine("price:\"" + line.UnitPrice + "\",                                    // Price");
                gastring.AppendLine("quantity:\"" + line.Qty + "\"                                         // Quantity");
                gastring.AppendLine("});");
}

<script type="text/javascript">
 gastring.ToString()
 ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

But when I am running this code, `gastring.ToString()` line generating javascript code as below:

```
ga(&#39;ecommerce:addItem&#39;, {
id:&quot;HGT678&quot;,       // Order ID
sku:&quot;HI789&quot;,                                     // SKU
name:&#39;Test Item 456&#39;,                                  // Product Name 
category:&quot; &quot;,                                    // Category
price:&quot;337.0000&quot;,                                    // Price
quantity:&quot;1&quot;                                         // Quantity
});
```

expected Output should be as below:

```
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
id:"HGT678",       // Order ID
sku:"HI789",                                     // SKU
name:"Test Item 456",                                  // Product Name 
category:" ",                                    // Category
price:"337.0000",                                    // Price
quantity:"1"                                         // Quantity
});
```

Need help on this issue.

Thanks,
Sandy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in ASP.NET MVC, strings are escaped by default, try [`Html.Raw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

```
@Html.Raw(gastring.ToString())
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to append escape char (\) before the single quote and double quote if you are adding any quote in between the AppendLine().

`System.Text.StringBuilder gastring = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
foreach (var line in OrderLines)
     {
         gastring.AppendLine("ga(\'ecommerce:addItem\', {");
                    gastring.AppendLine("id:\""+ line.OrderNumber  +"\",  // Order ID");
                    gastring.AppendLine("sku:\""+ line.SkuCode  +"\",                                     // SKU");
                    gastring.AppendLine("name:\""+ Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(line.SkuName) + "\", ");
                    gastring.AppendLine("category:\""+  +"\" ,    // Category");
                    gastring.AppendLine("price:\""+ line.UnitPrice +"\",    // Price");
                    gastring.AppendLine("quantity:\" "+ line.Qty  +"\"   // Quantity");
                    gastring.AppendLine("});");
    }       
        <script type="text/javascript">
         gastring.ToString()
         ga('ecommerce:send');
        </script>`

Comment: Escape single quotes in .Net strings ? Never heard of that.

Comment: run the above code and you will get the appropriate result.

Comment: That's not the proper way to handle this kind of case and it involves complicated string tricks. See Michaël Hompus answer.